# Element not found with locator: EmailId and locatorType: id

Tags: python

Baseclassmethod
def openQAUrl(self):
driver = webdriver.Chrome(URLPath.pathch)
driver.get(Url.baseurl)
driver.maximize_window()
return driver

```
def openSheet(self):
    sheetpath = "C:\\Data.xlsx"
    sheetname = "credentials"
    wb = OS.load_workbook(sheetpath)
    ws = wb[sheetname]
    email = ws.cell(2, 1).value
    pwd = ws.cell(2, 2).value
    return email, pwd
```

class Test_URL:

```
def testURL(self):
    baseMethods = BaseClassMethods(self)
    driver = baseMethods.openQAUrl()
    emailpwd = baseMethods.openSheet()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10000)
    baseMethods.sendKeys(driver, "EmailId", "id", emailpwd[0])
    baseMethods.sendKeys(driver, "//*[@id='Password']", emailpwd[1])
    baseMethods.click(driver, "//*[@id='divLoginWrapperLnkBtn']")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm getting error as Element not found with locator and locator type. Help me to resolve this error